# Generating a set of Rules that defines a Group of users ( Multivariate Analysis )

Tags: machine-learning, r, data-mining, predictive-modeling

I am working on a Multivariate Analysis on my dataset, I have a large dataset of 50k users let's call it (Loyal Users) with various numerical attributes +13 tracking the user's activity and events within a timeframe.
I want to come up with Set of rules to define this group of users so that i can come up with a common pattern.
This is an example of the data that i am working on

```
username        Like     Share           Select     Send  Verify  Register

Alex            524      329             203        787    1       1
Kristina        197      186             286        120    0       1
```

Here is an example of rules that i want to make : 
If Share > 23 and Verify =1 and Like >120  then Loyal User

would that be possible after doing a principal components analysis (PCA) and linear discriminant analysis (LDA) ? And how can i do that ?

Any ideas would be great.